# Частотный анализ текста

Tags: freepascal

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Мне нужно написать программу, в которой пользователь задает несколько букв, на которые должны начинаться слова в тексте, текст он тоже набирает сам. Так вот, у меня получилось написать программу только для того случая, когда слова начинаются с точно таких же букв, которые вводит пользователь, но ведь нужно считать слова, начинающиеся не только на прописные, но и на заглавные буквы (или наоборот).

```
uses crt;
var s,alf:string;
    i,j,k,l:integer;
    p:array[1..100] of integer;
BEGIN
  clrscr;
  writeln('Введите текст');
  readln(s);
  writeln('Введите количество букв, на которые должны начинаться слова ');
  readln(k);
  writeln('Введите буквы, на которые должны начинаться слова ');
  for i:=1 to k do
    readln(alf[i]);
  l:=0;
  for i:=1 to k do
    if s[1]=alf[j] then inc(l);
  p[1]:=l;
  for j:=1 to k do begin
    l:=0;
    for i:=2 to length(s) do
      if (s[i]=alf[j]) and (s[i-1]=' ') then inc(l);
    p[j]:=l;
    write(p[j],' ');
    end;
  readln;
END.
```

Comment: извиняюсь, что код так съехал, когда писала вопрос, он был нормальным...

Comment: Прописные и заглавные буквы - одно и то же. Вы имеете ввиду строчные.

Answer (score 1):

> но ведь нужно считать слова, начинающиеся не только на прописные, но и на заглавные буквы (или наоборот).

В freepascal есть функция lowercase(s), где s - строка. Она вернет вам строку, где все буквы преобразованы в строчные. Возможно, нужно подключить sysutils

```
Uses sysutils;
```

> Так вот, у меня получилось написать программу только для того случая, когда слова начинаются с точно таких же букв, которые вводит пользователь

Я вам уже отвечал в другом вопросе касательно использования индексов. Если вы работаете только с латинскими символами, то они представлены в кодировке ascii, где каждому символу соответствует целочисленное значение. Всего ascii символов 127 в обычном наборе.
Заведем массив на 127 элементов:

```
p:array[0..127] of integer;
```

Далее вы считываете строку и бежите по ней в цикле:

```
length:integer;
c:char;
char_code:integer;
...
length := Length(s);
for i:=1 to length do
    c := s[i]; 
    char_code := ord(c);
    p[char_code] := p[char_code] + 1
```

Функция

```
ord(c)
```

, где c - символ, возвращает ascii код символа. В итоге в массиве p в элементе с индексом <index> будет лежать то, сколько раз в строке встретился символ с ascii-кодом <index>.